# Finding solutions on GitHub and Stack Overflow

Tags: python, stackexchange, selenium, webdriver, google-chrome

The first part of the code opens Chrome and navigates to GitHub. If I don't find my solution, I open a new tab with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>. Then my code goes to Stack Overflow and searches there for solutions.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import *
import time
import keyboard

q = input("what is your programming question : ")+(' python')
class github :
    path = "c:/users/admin/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

    driver.get("https://github.com/")
    question = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    time.sleep(3)


    question.send_keys(q)
    question.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl+t"):
            driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
            driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
            question_2 = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

            question_2.send_keys(q)
            question_2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            break
```

Comment: Did you consider using URL like `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=test` for the search, instead of finding DOM element, and entering keystrokes  ? You can add filters of your own, like tags `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+test+%5Bpython%5D` where `%5B` is `[` and `%5D` is `]`

Comment: I would argue that the class isn't necessary here, since this seems like a small script.

Comment: @Linny I know that the class wasn't necessary.  I wanted to be more comfortabel using classes and to get to know it better.

Comment: Scrapy should be your choice if you are interested in using classes. In Python, it's not like Java where you have to put class everywhere. Modular code with functions is good enough.

Answer (score 5):

### Selenium

Selenium imposes a lot of overhead and complexity that you don't need to deal with. If you needed to scrape, use `requests` + `beautifulsoup`; but you don't: StackExchange has a [good API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), so you should strongly prefer using that. It will get you results more efficiently and the results will be more accurate and less fragile.

### PEP8

```
class github :
```

should be

```
class Github:
```

Answer (score 5):

For simply content scraping without JavaScript and ajax content try [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) for best practices. Scrapy uses Python classes by default as it is a Python framework.

Easy tutorial to learn Scrapy:

[Scrapy Tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkA1cWN4DEc&list=PLZyvi_9gamL-EE3zQJbU5N3nzJcfNeFHU)

[Official site of ScrappingHub](https://www.scrapinghub.com/learn-scrapy#get-started-scrapy-tutorials)

Selenium is good for scraping dynamic content and causes unnecessary overhead as mentioned in above answer.

For above code:
Try avoiding `time.sleep` and use `EC.presence_of_element_located` and similar functions to obtain desired behavior. [Selenium Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)